# Does the gas in blood remain constant when breathing? Is O2 and CO2 replaced by N?

Tags: breathing, pulmonology

Am a software dev and working on a non-scientific game that shall include "somewhat realistic" elements of the pulmonary system.
Effectively I want to roughly model the exchange of O2 and CO2 between blood and air when breathing.

From what I was able to gather here, roughly 20% of O2 are bound to blood when we are at full saturation: https://www.cvphysiology.com/Microcirculation/M002
Furthermore that O2 is replaced by CO2 due to our metabolic processes. As a result, the gas remains roughly constant (ignoring what's solved in the water and plasma).

However what happens if a human exhales all their air and then breathes an atmosphere of pure Nitrogen (besides suffocating, obviously)?
Will the exhaled gas contain any O2 or CO2? If yes, does that mean N is solved into blood in significant amounts? I haven't been able to confirm the later at all. Or does the overall gas concentration in blood decrease after all?

Hope someone has a rough answer.

Huge thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want the model to be "somewhat realistic," no one should be able to exhale all their air.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but my take is that there will initially be some CO2 diffusing from the dissolved CO2 in the blood into the pure N2 in the lungs and thus exhaled if there is breathing.  This will continue while the body's remaining metabolism continues to produce more CO2 and the heart moves blood, which primarily transports it as bicarbonate and carbonic acid.(1)  There would probably be trace amounts of O2 diffusing into the lungs.  There would probably be only slightly more N2 in the blood, as the partial pressure of N2 would not change much between air and pure N2.

I'm not sure what you meant by "the gas remains roughly constant" as the O2 and CO2 (and N2) in the blood are not in gaseous form.  They exist as dissolved molecules in the aqueous plasma, not as bubble of gas.

(1) ["Transport of Carbon Dioxide in the Blood"](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/wm-biology2/chapter/transport-of-carbon-dioxide-in-the-blood/)